# unique records in mysql one-to-many join without DISTINCT or GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, sql

Here's the basic query:

```
SELECT
    some_columns
FROM
    d
JOIN
    m ON d.id = m.d_id
JOIN
    s ON s.id = m.s_id
JOIN
    p ON p.id = s.p_id
WHERE
    some_criteria   
ORDER BY
    d.date DESC
LIMIT 25
```

Table `m` can contain multiple `s_id`s per each `d_id`. Here's a super simple example:

```
+--------+--------+------+
| id     | d_id   | s_id |
+--------+--------+------+
| 317354 | 291220 |  642 |
| 317355 | 291220 |   32 |
+--------+--------+------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Which we want. But, obviously, it's producing duplicate `d` records in this particular query.

These tables have lots of columns, and I need to edit these down due to the sensitive nature of the data, but here's the basic structure as it pertains to this query:

```
| d  | CREATE TABLE `d` (
  `id` bigint(22) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `date` (`date`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB |

| m | CREATE TABLE `m` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `d_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `s_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `is_king` binary(1) DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `d_id` (`d_id`),
  KEY `is_king` (`is_king`),
  KEY `s_id` (`s_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB |

| s | CREATE TABLE `s` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `p_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `p_id` (`p_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB |

| p | CREATE TABLE `p` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB |
```

Now, previously, we had a `GROUP BY d.id` in place to grab uniques. The data here are now huge, so we can no longer realistically do that. `SELECT DISTINCT d.id` is even slower.

Any ideas? Everything I come up with creates a problem elsewhere.

Comment: subqueries instead of joins?

Comment: Please post the `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for each of those. Do they have indexes defined? Do they have `FOREIGN KEY` relationships defined on the joining columns (which enforces appropriate indexing)? That alone will likely make a giant improvement in performance.

Comment: If you can guarantee all joins will get matches you can do that select limit and after it do the joins. If you cannot you ill end with less than 25 rows

Comment: So... you are not interested in the s_id's, or do you just want a random one of those 2?

Comment: Based on that sample result set, _duplicate_ isn't the right word here. `d_id` is repeated yes, but in relation to the other columns it is all still `DISTINCT`.  For any given value of `d_id`, what other values (`id, s_id`) should be chosen? The highest, the lowset, the most recent?  `GROUP BY` isn't especially meaningful without an aggregate like `MAX(),MIN(),COUNT()`, despite what MySQL permits you to do with it - you need to be specific to the RDBMS which other values it should be returning in relation to the grouped column (`d_id`)

Comment: How many condition are in some criteria?

Comment: I am in interested in the `s_id`. One of those `s_id`s can be the King, but I can't, for example, limit records to `WHERE s_id_type='king', since I'll omit everything else.` A given `d_id` may not have any kings (in this particular query), but I'd want it to show up anyway.

Comment: Please post the relevant `SHOW CREATE TABLE <tablename>` statements so we can see the indexing and all the columns.

Answer (score 0):

Does changing "JOIN m ON d.id = m.d_id" to "LEFT JOIN m ON d.id = m.d_id" accomplish what you're looking for here?

I'm not sure I understand your goal clearly, but "table m contains many rows per each d" immediately has me wondering if you should be using some other type of join to accomplish your ends.